# USB Breakout Infrared

Tags: usb, infrared, breakout

"[Usb breakouts](https://cdn.sparkfun.com//assets/parts/9/4/4/0/12700-01.jpg)" provide power, ground and signals in. [Infrared receiver diodes](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10266) need power, a ground and a signal out. Will the USB breakout transmit data out from the infrared diode if connected? If so, I'm guessing a program such as LIRC could receive the data, or is there some native Linux (or otherwise) software that listens to raw signals coming from a USB port?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, USB does not work like that. It's a heavily complicated, processed and enumerated protocol and cannot be used for directly connecting raw signals.

Those active IR receivers can be connected through rs232 serial ports.

Comment: Also, even the slowest USB communications are too fast for standard IR modules.